# Linked List trying to swap two linked list assignment error

Tags: c++

```
Contact * l = head;
Contact * t;
Contact * s;
int temp;
int temp2;
int temp3;
int x;
int checkfield=0;
t=l;
while(t!=NULL)
{
    s=t->GetNext();
    while(s!=NULL)
    {
        enum Field {ID, NAME, CITY, STATE, ZIP};
        if(field==1)
        {
            if(t->GetID()>s->GetID())
                checkfield=1;
                temp=t->GetID();
                temp2= s->GetID();
                s->GetID()=temp;
```

---

int Contact::GetID(){ return id; } //This is the GetID Function

---

For some reason, for the `s->GetID()=temp` it says "the expression is not assignable" Why is this the case and how can I solve this?
}

Comment: Does `GetID()` return a reference? Can you show the body of `GetID()`?

Comment: Agreed. I think we need to see the definition of `Contact` or at least `Contact::GetID`.

Comment: int Contact::GetID(){ return id; }

//This is the GetID Function. It simply returns the id number

Comment: Ok. I just edited the question. Sorry. This is only my 2nd time using this website. Just learned about Stack Overflow

Comment: You cannot modify this get function. You need a set function `void Contact::SetID(int i){id = i;}` then swap `temp=t->GetID(); t->SetID(s->GetID()); s->SetID(temp);` I am not sure what other node variables you have. Swap might be more complicated.